# how to display message in joomla using javascript

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I want to display a message after clicking a button in Joomla using:

```
Joomla.renderMessages({"success":"this is test message"});
```

[image]

but it displays the characters vertically and in descending order, whereas I want to display it like so:

> this is test message

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It expects the messages to be passed in an array, even if there is only a single message, ie

```
Joomla.renderMessages({"success":["this is test message"]});
```

The formatting example given in the source code for the renderMessages function (\media\system\js\core-uncompressed.js) is:

```
var messages = {
     "message": ["Message one", "Message two"],
     "error": ["Error one", "Error two"]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is great, below is some code to add a title to the message. As a side note, you can also load other strings & use those to create a custom alert. The title of the string is added to the alerts main class.

`Joomla.JText.load({success: "Success", custom_alert: "Custom Alert"});`

`Joomla.renderMessages({'success': ['This has a title!'], 'custom_alert': ['This has a title!']});`

[image: custom message]

As you can see above the custom alert has the class alert-custom_alert added.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one more layer to complete the above 2 posts which are really good. If you want to use the translation service from Joomla, you can do that by doing the following:

1. Add this in your php code, I add this to my default.php file at the top

   ```
   JText::script('COM_YOURCOMPONENT_YOUR_MESSAGE');
   ```
2. In your JS file, add this code to the logic where your want to display the message

   ```
   var message = Joomla.JText._('COM_YOURCOMPONENT_YOUR_MESSAGE');
   Joomla.JText.load({success: "Success"});
   Joomla.renderMessages({'success': [message]});
   ```
3. In your Language/en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcomponent.ini file, add the translation

   ```
   COM_YOURCOMPONENT_YOUR_MESSAGE="your message"
   ```